# Message box not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to follow an example (image printscreen) but I am not receiving this pink box with the message before the print output:

> ```
> "Will train until cv error hasn't decreased in 50 rounds.
> Stopping Best Iteration:
> [140] : ---"
> ```

What should I do to have it showing?
[image: example I want to follow]

Function :

```
def modelfit(alg, dtrain, predictors,useTrainCV=True, cv_folds=5, early_stopping_rounds=50):
  
    if useTrainCV:
        xgb_param = alg.get_xgb_params()
        xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(dtrain[predictors].values, label=dtrain[target].values)
        cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], nfold=cv_folds,
            metrics='auc', early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
        alg.set_params(n_estimators=cvresult.shape[0])
    
    #Fit the algorithm on the data
    alg.fit(dtrain[predictors], dtrain['is_canceled'],eval_metric='auc')
        
    #Predict training set:
    dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(dtrain[predictors])
    dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(dtrain[predictors])[:,1]
        
    #Print model report:
    print("\nModel Report")
    print("Accuracy : %.4g" % metrics.accuracy_score(dtrain['is_canceled'].values, dtrain_predictions))
    print("AUC Score (Train): %f" % metrics.roc_auc_score(dtrain['is_canceled'], dtrain_predprob))
```

Set up :

```
#Import libraries:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn import metrics   #Additional scklearn functions
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 4

train = df
target = 'is_canceled'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: actually, it is just not showing up! I looked anywhere on the internet to see if that is a config / code line I'm missing! I'm following everything from that notebook , this is the only difference

Comment: Please add some reproducible code so people can help.

Comment: tried Silent=False but does not change anything

Comment: @RobinSage , just edited the post with the function I am using